# mod_rewrites in nested .htaccess causing strange 404

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have an apache HTTP server with a directory structure as such:

```
/
---- api/
---- ---- index.php
---- ---- .htaccess
---- index.php
---- .htaccess
```

**/.htaccess**:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/
```

**/api/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
```

My objective was to display the index.php of a directory when it was called without a trailing backslash. However, calling http://domain.com/api results in a 404. Commmenting out the one line in */api/.htaccess* causes everything to work as expected.

I'm having a hard time understanding this behavior as the [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) for *RewriteEngine On* says nothing about it. Could someone shed some light on mod_rewrite's workings here?

Note: This question was originally posted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402343/mod-rewrites-in-nested-htaccess-causing-strange-404) but received no response. I will close it if this one solves the issue.

**EDIT**: As per @Jonah B's suggestion that a new rewrite context might be created, I tried changing the rules of */api/.htaccess* to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

but the result remains the same - it still 404s.

Comment: You might need to add a "RewriteBase /api/" to that configuration, though it should not be necessary if DocumentRoot is set correctly. You can see what apache is doing in the rewrite engine by using trace logging: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: Increasing logging gives me a bunch of nice information when the page works (i.e. when the second .htaccess is empty), but just this when it 404s: ```[Sat Sep 10 21:13:31.743425 2016] [core:info] [pid 3704:tid 1008] [client a.b.c.d:31361] AH00129: Attempt to serve directory: C:/dir1/dir2/www.domain.com/api```.

Comment: Then the rewrite engine is not initialized. Try getting rid of the RewriteEngine directive but leaving the RewriteRule directive.

Comment: Still the same result =/. It's pretty easy to reproduce, I can send you my host directory if you'd like (Just like 4 files and a directory).

Comment: Then it sounds like the DirectorySlash Off directive is preventing an internal rewrite to /api/ which would allow it to visit the subdirectory. Turning it on may help. Again, though, it sounds like the desired behavior is available with DirectoryIndex without using the rewrite engine.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Using directoryindex doesn't change the behavior at all, but using it with directoryslash turned off sends 301s again, which I don't want.

Comment: The behavior is reproducible. The problem appears to be that when DirectorySlash is off, and the request lacks a trailing slash, and the main logical to physical mapping resolves it to a subdirectory, and the rewrite engine is engaged, then the results of executing the rewrite rules, in a subrequest, does not wind up being picked up by the main request. This smells like a DirectorySlash bug, but it's not clear, there may be a formulation of RewriteOptions and flags that yields the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to tell apache that a request to route

```
/api
```

should look for an index.php file in the directory /api maps to, use

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Don't bother with the rewrite engine.

See:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default

Comment: You really haven't read the question.

Comment: If the observation is that explicitly providing a RewriteEngine On directive in a subdirectory .htaccess causes parent directory RewriteRules to be ignored, the implication is that .htaccess is creating a new rewrite context that lacks the rules defined in the parent directory .htaccess. And with DirectorySlash off, no internal redirect to /api/ is occurring.

Comment: Now *that* is very interesting. I'll test and get back in a sec. EDIT: Question updated.